# How to implement JWT + Oauth2.0 auth in parallel

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth

i read all the internet and all the docs but there is no one word about how to implement multiple authentication in one service. What i need to do ? I wanna that user will have an choise how to authenticate with Oauth or base JWT authentication (my own)

i have my filterChain method

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(httpSecurityCorsConfigurer -> httpSecurityCorsConfigurer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req ->
                        req.requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST_URL)
                                .permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole(ADMIN.name(), SUPER_ADMIN.name())
                                .requestMatchers("/superAdmin/admin/{userId}").hasRole(SUPER_ADMIN.name())
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()

                )
                .oauth2Login(
                        customizer-> {

                        }
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout(logout ->
                        logout.logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
                                .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext())
                )
        ;

        return http.build();
    }
```

and i also provide my oauth information in .yml file

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            client-id:id
            client-secret: secret
```

Comment: Handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous, thats why there is no ”jwtfilter” in spring security so why are you doing something dengerous? Oauth2login will authenticate and create a cookie session with your backend, and you then want a second logon type that is insecure, it doesnt make sense.